# Controlling (hiding, showing) columns with VBA based on other columns structure

Tags: excel, vba, hide, show

I can't figure out the right logic for the VBA to set (hide or show) the columns in some area (columns K to O) based on the "template" area (columns C to G).
In the example below, I hid the column D and I would like to run a code that would scan what columns in range C3 to G3 are hidden or shown and accordingly (show or hide columns) edit the columns in range K3 to O3, which in this example means hiding the column L.
I can work with ranges and can further edit the code for my purposes, but I just don't know how to somehow save the column structure in the template and replicate it in the second area.
Also, there will be formulas in the template and nulls in the edited area, but I think I can do this adjustment on my own.
I will be grateful for any idea.

[image: Example of columns]

Comment: Use the `hidden`-property of a column: `Activesheet.Range("K3").entireColumn.hidden = Activesheet.Range("C3").entireColumn.hidden`

Comment: Didn't you find some time to check the answered you received and send some feedback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the next code, please:

```
Sub testHideUnhide()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, rng As Range, cel As Range
 
 Set sh = ActiveSheet 'use here your sheet, if not the active one
 Set rng = sh.Range("C3:G3")
 For Each cel In rng.cells
    cel.Offset(0, 9).EntireColumn.Hidden = cel.EntireColumn.Hidden
 Next
```

It will hide and unhide the columns in rage "K:O" according to "C:G" situation, from this point of view.

Answer (score 1):

### Hide Columns With Offset

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub hideCols()
    
    Const src As String = "C:G"
    Const dst As String = "K:O"
   
    Dim n As Long
    For n = 1 To Columns(dst).Count
        Columns(dst).Columns(n).Hidden = Columns(src).Columns(n).Hidden
    Next n
    
End Sub
```